# javascript: How to globalise a variable from closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a global service and want to expose the global variable across all the scripts on the page.
For ex: MyService variable should be available in all scripts. This is just like jQuery which is available to all the scripts on the page.

I was looking at jQuery 3.1.1 source code.

```
( function( global, factory ) {

"use strict";

if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

    // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
    // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
    // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
    // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
    // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
    // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
    // See ticket #14549 for more info.
    module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
} else {
    factory( global );
}

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

Above is a small portion from the start.

And this is where jQuery `var` is declared

```
var
version = "3.1.1",

// Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {

    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
},
```

As per my understanding this is inside a closure I tried to do something similar.

```
(function (jQuery) {
    var MyService = function() {
        console.log('hello world from service');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

If I include the above script in my html page and try to access MyService javascript interpreter throws error `MyService is not defined` which I is correct as that is defined inside a closure.

To resolve this I have to declare `var MyService` outside the closure which I don't want to do.

My question is

1. How can I achieve the desired result.
2. Why it is not failing in case of jQuery.

Comment: 1: remove the word `var` or 2 use `window.MyService =`

Comment: You miss the part in jQuery source code where they expose it globally: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`

Comment: @Ritesh I'm not sure what you mean. My previous comment was regarding: `Why it is not failing in case of jQuery`?!

Comment: @A.Wolff Got it ignore previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(function (jQuery, w) {
w.MyService = function() {
    console.log('hello world from service');
}
})(jQuery, window);
```

Try this ;)

Comment: This way MyService is defined as property on windows object and than everywhere I have to use `window.MyService` but we are not using `window.jQuery` to use jQuery

Comment: You can use both `MyService` or `window.MyService` ...
Same for JQuery try `window.JQuery` it works ;)

Comment: Got it. Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting attributes on the window object like so:

`window['hello'] = 'world';`

Answer (score 0):

This is not closure. This is self invoking function.
Another way

```
var globalVar = {};
(function (jQuery, g) {
g.MyService = function() {
    console.log('hello world from service');
}
})(jQuery, globalVar);
```

Need Not to change anything in `window`

```
// Output

globalVar.MyService()
hello world from service
```